# Flash Triggering AS Code on a Frame

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm a Flex developer who had to do some coding in Flash, so my understanding of how putting an action on a time line is somewhat limited.

I'm trying to attach this action on the first frame of the movie that I'm planning play. When I play the movie for the first time, the code executes as expected. However, when I restart or rewind to the first frame of the movie, the code no longer executes. I'm not sure why this is happening, as it seemed added actionscript code to a frame seems pretty straight forward.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;


var urlLoader:URLLoader;
var timer:Timer;

startAdPlay();

function startAdPlay():void
{
    if( urlLoader == null ) {
        urlLoader = new URLLoader();
    }

    urlLoader.load( new URLRequest(  "http://localhost:20081/startadplay/15" ) );

    timer = new Timer( (15 * 1000) );
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, stopAdPlay );
    timer.start();
}

function stopAdPlay(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    urlLoader.load( new URLRequest(  "http://localhost:20081/stopadplay" ) );

    timer.stop();
    stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't call `startAdPlay()` while restarting the movie in app

Comment: I assume that call is that stand alone line, startAdPlay() is being call on restart, no?

Comment: no. did I understood correctly that you restart movie manually (i.e. without launching swf)? In that case you should do `startAdPlay()` while restarting

Comment: So how would I call startAdPlay() on restart? I restart the movie manually to test the function call.

Comment: So you hang restart e.g. on some button, in that case you should hang `startAdPlay()` on `MOUSE_CLICK` event of button.

Comment: I actually want to hang it on the timeline. There isn't any user interaction with the movie.

Comment: @Wit,and how do you scroll timeline? I suppose you do `mc.gotoAndPlay`?

Comment: I got it, the URLLoader was caching the url request, so it seemed like the url was not getting called.

Comment: hm! really! `?nocache=timestamp` will help you

Answer (score 2):

Given that you are already a Flex developer and thus used to writing your code in separate files outside Flash, I would recommend keep doing that and put as little code as possible on the timeline. Purists will recommend no code at all on the timeline, but I will put function calls and dispatchEvent() commands on the timeline. The actual function being called is defined in a separate .as file however.

So in your case I would just put the startAdPlay(); function call on the timeline, and put the actual function body in a separate class that is linked to the Flash movie in the Properties window. That'll make it more logical when and where the function is defined.

Comment: I come close to being a purist, in this case, but the occasional stop() is sometimes an easy solution compared to setting up a frame label listener, which i will typically do in most cases.

Comment: I have not had to touch Flash until now, so I'm just trying to get the code to work. I will be definitely be refactoring to your suggestion to make my job easier to maintain the code.

Comment: It's an advantage to start doing it now, don't wait to refactor later. Code in the timeline can sometimes make it confusing when different functions and variables are being created versus when they actually live in the global scope and are being shared.